# How to Delete Rows After Grouping With Maximum Performance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-delete

Given is the following table:

```
Table Before: TABLE_FOO

| TEST_ID | RUN_ID |
|---------|--------|
| 1000    | 10     | 
| 1000    | 11     |
| 1000    | 12     | <-- keep
| 2000    | 20     |
| 2000    | 21     | <-- keep
| 3000    | 30     | <-- keep
```

I need to clean all rows where the `RUN_ID` is **not** the maximum ID per `TEST_ID` so that the table looks as follows:

```
Table After: TABLE_FOO

| TEST_ID | RUN_ID |
|---------|--------|
| 1000    | 12     |
| 2000    | 21     |
| 3000    | 30     |
```

My best attempt so far:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_FOO 
WHERE RUN_ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(RUN_ID) FROM TABLE_FOO GROUP BY TEST_ID)
```

Performance is critical. Do you think that there is a faster/more efficient way?

Comment: Post your best attempt of your  `DELETE` query..

Comment: As part of the exercise, at least start by selecting the elements you want to keep (or the ones you want to delete). That will help you visualize some paths forward.

Comment: @PM 77-1 I added my best attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any grouping or something. Just use below query -

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_FOO T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT RUN_ID
              FROM TABLE_FOO T2
              WHERE T1.TEST_ID = T2.TEST_ID
              AND T1.RUN_ID < T2.RUN_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will confirm the list you need to delete

```
Select * from tbl a where exists(select 1 from tbl b where a.test_Id = b.Test_id and a.RUN_ID  < b.RUN_ID )
```

The delete query once you are sure of the list is

```
Delete from tbl a where exists(select 1 from tbl b where a.test_Id = b.Test_id and a.RUN_ID  < b.RUN_ID )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go for:

```
delete from t
    where t.run_id <> (select max(t2.run_id) from t t2 where t2.test_id = t.test_id);
```

This directly captures the logic you are looking for.